# How to program external EEPROM using USBtinyISP or Pocket AVR programmer

Tags: eeprom

I want to write data into an external EEPROM from my computer using USBtinyISP or Pocket AVR programmer. Is it possible to do that? I know they can be used to program microcontrollers, but not sure if I can use them to program EEPROM.

If they can't, any suggestions?

Comment: i know arduino can program both microcontroller and EEPROM. what else can do both? any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately they can't; the programmers contain firmware that is specific to programming AVR microcontrollers. You will need to either reprogram them to "talk" EEPROM instead of AVR, or use a separate EEPROM programmer.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what OP was asking and thought that he wanted to program EEPROM of an AVR.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can. See http://www.nomad.ee/micros/memdude.shtml for how to program EEPROMS. Programming old-school EPROMS needs a bit more hardware, but is also doable, see http://www.nomad.ee/micros/eprom/index.shtml.

As you can see, the USBtinyUSB can be used as generic USB to SPI bridge with its default firmware, so you can hook anything that behaves like SPI slave up to it.